# Union of normal spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ a topological space and $X= \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ are open for all $i \in I$ and $U_i \cap U_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$, if each $(U_i, \mathcal{T}_{U_i})$ is normal then $X$ is normal.

I don't know how to start the proof. I know that I have to take $A,B \subset X$ closed, but I can't continue

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that if $V \subseteq U_i$ is open in $U_i$ (i.e, with the topology $\tau_{U_i}$), then $V$ is open in $X$. (why?)

Suppose $A, B \subseteq X$ are closed and disjoint. By definition of the subspace topologies then, $A \cap U_i, B \cap U_i$ are closed in $U_i$ for each $i \in I$. Then since $U_i$ are normal we have disjoint $V_i, W_i$ open in $U_i$ such that $A \cap U_i \subseteq V_i$, $B \cap U_i \subseteq W_i$.

Then $V_i, W_i$ are open and disjoint in $X$ for every $i \in I$, and then notice that $V = \cup_{i \in I}V_i$ and $W = \cup_{i\in I}W_i$ does the trick of separating $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What guarantees that $V$ and $W$ are disjoint? What prevents $V_i \cap W_j \neq \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274039/countable-union-of-normal-spaces for further discussion and a link to a proof.