# Countable union of normal spaces

Tags: general-topology

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $(X_n, \tau_n)$ a normal space such that $(X_n, \tau_n)$ is a subspace of $(X_{n+1}, \tau_{n+1})$. Let $X=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ and $\tau$ the topology induced by the family of topological spaces. Prove that $(X, \tau)$ is normal.

**My attempt**. Let $A,B \subset X$ closed subsets such that $A \cap B=\emptyset$, then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $A_n=A \cap X_n$ and $B_n=B \cap X_n$ then $A_n$ and $B_n$ are closed in $X_n$ and $A_n \cap B_n=\emptyset$. Since $X_n$ is normal exist $M_n, N_n \in \tau_n$ such that $A_n \subset M_n$ and $B_n \subset N_n$ and also $M_n=X_n \cap U_n$, $ N_n=X_n \cap V_n$ where $U_n, V_n \in \tau$ and $M_n \cap N_n = \emptyset$. Let $U=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ and $V=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} V_n$. But I'm not sure if $ U \cap V=\emptyset$ because I can't prove that.

Comment: The answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928208/union-of-normal-spaces offers your proof as a solution to this problem. But I agree with you that it doesn't establish that $U \cap V = \emptyset$, since you have no guarantee that $U_i \cap V_j  = \emptyset$ when $i \neq j$.

Comment: Proposition 3.1 on this page on [colimits of normal spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+of+normal+spaces) gives a complete proof of a slightly more general statement. The trick is to define the $U_i$ and $V_i$ recursively so that $U_i$ and $V_j$ are disjoint for all $i$ and $j$, by arranging for the closures $\overline{U_i}$ and $\overline{V_j}$ to be disjoint. I can write this up as an answer, if this isn't clear.

Comment: I did not understand the part of the closures

Comment: And that proposition 3.1 talks about subsets that are *closed* in the final space.

Comment: You do need that each $X_n$ is closed in $X_{n+1}$ for 3.1 on that page to apply. And if you don't understand that proof fully, edit your question accordingly and make it about that.